# Get failed to generate signed APK on (in app:mergeReleaseResources task)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I want to Generate signed APK, I'll get the following error:

[image]

UPDATE: some of log details after run Generate signed APK

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
```

Comment: And, have you checked the logs ? And please, the next time just post the text of the exception, there is no need to post an image on which we will have to zoom in just to read a single line of text.

Comment: Thanks @Dvorog for your explain. I'll update question and insert exception.

Comment: @alimodares to get the logs you can go to the Terminal window and run "gradlew :app:mergeReleaseResources" and update the question with the output. The errors will be present in the build log.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.